# '.ctor' is not a valid identifier

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2008

In visual studio 2008 when open the design for a VB.Net windows form, i am getting the error " '.ctor' is not a valid identifier". I can see the form designer if I press the "Ignore and Continue" link.
All other forms are loading fine.

The callstack with the error message:

```
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.CodeDomEventBindingService.ValidateMethodName(String methodName)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.EventBindingService.EventPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(Object component, Object value)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeAttachEventStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeAttachEventStatement statement)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeStatement statement)
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: If you don't load the form but simply build the project, does it compile successfully? If not, can you post any error messages that you get? If you cannot build it using VS, try using MSBuild on .vbproj file from command line.

Answer (score 17):

This message may indicate that you accidently have overwritten the constructor. As far as I know, M$ VStudio instanciates your form to display it in the designer window.

Maybe the following steps will help

- Check, if you have a Sub with your class name defined in your .vb-file (for example: "Private Sub YOURCLASS (...) Handles MyBase.Load" instead of "Private Sub YOURCLASS_load (...) Handles MyBase.Load" )
- go into the Solution Explorer (nice name, isn't it)
- rebuild the whole solution

Best regards

Comment: Forgot to tell: if the check in the first step succeeds and you really find such a sub, then rename it

Comment: Thanks! Saved me from rebuilding a huge Active Report for no reason!  When the report was converted from an earlier version, the _PageEnd was left off the sub name for the PageEnd event handler, and I didn't see it!  Don't know why this was down-voted.  (+1)

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution would be rebuilding the form from scratch and that probably won't give an error.
The Visual Studio designer sometimes create code the designer itself won't understand.

Some other steps to make sure you're not watching an old designer dll file.

Close the designer for the file
Clean the project and rebuild
Start the application
Open the designer

This should force the designer to reload the file.

The designer also seems to block all network traffic, if you do anything with remoting/webservices it probably won't work and cause unexpected error while designing.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error came when I had declared a constructor but hadn't defined it.
You can check for the same in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


Private Sub Form1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
```

`tenia repetido` handles MyBase.load